# Is it compulsory in scala to have _= in setter

Tags: scala

i am confused why to use _= in setter Method in Scala i have wrote a program without using _= and also using _= the output is same.
Please help me with my confusion actually i am new in Scala

```
class BankAccount {
  private var _balance = 0
  def balance = _balance
  def balance(bal:Int) = {_balance=bal}
def deposit(amount:Int): Unit =
  {
    _balance = amount
  }
}

object bank extends App {
  val bankAccount = new BankAccount
  bankAccount.deposit(1500)
  println(bankAccount.balance) //1500
  bankAccount.balance(6000)
  println(bankAccount.balance) /6000

}
```

Is _= only naming Convention or it plays any role ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to use the `_=` convention for your code example.

```
private var _balance = 0
def balance:Int = _balance            //the getter
def balance_=(bal:Int) {_balance=bal} //the setter
def deposit(amount:Int): Unit = {_balance = amount}
```

Usage:

```
val bankAccount = new BankAccount
bankAccount.deposit(1500)
println(bankAccount.balance) //1500
bankAccount.balance = 6000   //this is how to use the setter
println(bankAccount.balance) //6000
```

Answer (score 4):

If you had the name as just `balance`, you would have a naming conflict on the getter method. I.e

```
class BankAccount {
  private var balance = 0
  def balance = balance //A naming conflict occurs here, as both the def and the variable are called balance.
  def balance(bal:Int) = balance = bal //Another conflict,as balance could refer to either the variable or the def    
}
```

As a side note, you wouldnt (shouldn't) really write code like that in scala. Mutable variables are not great, so ideally you'd have the following class instead:

```
case class BankAccount(balance: Int = 0)
```

This will make `balance` immutable and automatically generate the getter for it.

```
val bank = BankAccount(300)
println(bank.balance)
```

If you needed to have it be mutable - which isn't really a good idea, or necessary - normally you'd just create a new instance of BankAccount. But if you needed it, you could easily make it mutable just by doing:

```
case class BankAccount(var balance: Int = 0)
```

Now a setter for balance will also be available, so you could do:

```
val bank = BankAccount(300)
bank.balance = 400
println(bank.balance) //Will print 400
```

Comment: But if i want my own setter function with some logic then in that case what is convention that i should follow to define my own setter function?

Comment: @Adibrajiwate If its purely a setter with no additional logic, then ideally you'd use a case class. If it contains additonal logic, then you should give it a descriptive name, e.g the `deposit()` method from your example.

Answer (score 0):

Is a convention.

You can check the official documentation on naming conventions in the following link.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html

Is important to follow conventions to ensure quality and manteinability of the code.

Comment: according to docs For accessors of properties, the name of the method should be the name of the property. But in above program if i set the getter name same as the property name it gives me an error